# Date issue with SOAP API (Oracle Rightnow Cloud Service)

Tags: rightnow-crm, oracle-service-cloud

I need some help with a SOAP API. I have made a website in which users enter data which is stored and retrieved from Service Cloud via SOAP API.

It was working fine until yesterday I have started facing a problem with dates. For example if I enter today's date `07/05/2016` it stores perfectly fine on RN but on data retrieval it randomly changes dates to (two days before, one day before) `05/05/2016`.

I know the UTC conversion but the behavior is so random I don't know whether to add one day or two days on data retrieval.

Please help this is a nightmare and totally freaking me out. And one more question: Could it be by any chance because of the new release [February 2016](http://documentation.custhelp.com/euf/assets/devdocs/february2015/Connect_Web_Services_for_SOAP/Default.htm)?

Answer (score 0):

Try different date formatting:

```
<ns2:GenericFields dataType="DATE" name="statement_date">
          <ns2:DataValue>
           <ns2:DateValue>2016-05-07</ns2:DateValue>
           </ns2:DataValue>
</ns2:GenericFields>
```